# How to check if a member is banned? Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there any possible way to get a list of Banned Users from a Guild so whenever someone is not Banned but still an user tries to Unban them an Error Message will be sent saying `User is not Banned`.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def unban1(self, ctx, *, member):
        banned_members = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user

            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                await ctx.guild.unban(user)
                await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code you posted, here's my new answer:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban1(self, ctx, member):
    user = await client.get_user(member.id)
    try:
        entry = await ctx.guild.get_ban(user)
    except discord.NotFound:
        await user.send('You are not in the ban list')
        return
    await ctx.send(f'{user.name} is in the ban list')
```

Comment: @xXSkillexZ I've edited this code: try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified through what method you want to check if the user is on the ban list. For example, you could do it through passing in the id of the user that you want to check on. Here's an example:

```py
@client.command()
async def is_banned(ctx, user_id : int):
    user = await client.get_user(user_id)
    try:
        entry = await ctx.guild.get_ban(user)
    except discord.NotFound:
        await user.send(You are not in the ban list')
        return
    await ctx.send(f'{user.name} is in the ban list')
```

To use this, you will have to run `<command_prefix>is_banned <id_of_user>` in the server. This will check if the user is banned or not. If the user is not banned, then the user will be sent a DM by the bot saying `You are not in the ban list`. However, if the user is banned, then the bot will print out `<user> is in the ban list` in the server.

Comment: If you don't want to get the ban information for all users but just for one you could use `guild.fetch_ban(user)` which raises `NotFound` if the user isn't banned.

Comment: I tried this but it does not seem working. I also fixed the line `await user.send('You are not in the ban list')`. Still nothing.

Comment: @xXskillexZ Can you edit your original question and enter your code there please, so that I can see what you're doing.

Comment: @AdityaTomar Edit my question

Comment: @xXSkillexZ also by the way, are you using `bot` or `client`? Also, I just added a new answer; let me know if it works for you. If it doesn't, let me know if it gives you any errors.

Comment: @AdityaTomar In my main file I use `client`. Alright let me check the other answer

Comment: @AdityaTomarI tried that but it doesn't seem working again. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did the other answer work? Also, are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Basically to ban a member you can use the `member.ban()` command. This will make the member banned and add it to the *list of banned users*, which you can find in `ctx.guild.bans()`.

If what you want to achieve is being able to ban someone and checking if he is in the banned users list before unbanning him, you can use the following sample commands:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_members = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
```